# dbDeploy.net for oracle database deployment automation using powershell

Tags: oracle11g, powershell-4.0, dbdeploy

I am looking for sample implementation of dbDeploy.net for oracle database deployment automation. I was able to find the github resource : https://github.com/brunomlopes/dbdeploy.net

But there is no example mentioned regarding how to implement it using powershell. Can anyone help me to provide some guidance with sample implementation.

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: I'm curious to know why you're using DBDeploy and not Flywaydb or DBUp, which are better maintained migrations frameworks?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. I need to take a look into it.

Comment: Flyway is probably better if you're using Java, DBUp and ReadyRoll for .NET. Let me know which you end up going for!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details. All these are good options.